# How to differentiate multiple GUI?

Tags: user-interface, autoit

My GUI brings up other GUIs once a button is pressed (works correctly).

But when I interact with the pop-up GUI, the main GUI reacts as well (an embedded IE browser; when it receives input it messes everything up). Here is the code:

```
#include <ButtonConstants.au3>
#include <EditConstants.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>
#include <StaticConstants.au3>
#include <ComboConstants.au3>
#include <WinHttp.au3>
#include <IE.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <GuiEdit.au3>
#include <WinAPIFiles.au3>
#include <ImageSearch2015.au3>

Opt('SendKeyDelay', Random(16, 80)); default 5. higher number = slower
Global $nameInfo = IniRead('Userinfo.ini', 'Name', 'Name', 'No username on file')
Global $passInfo = IniRead('Userinfo.ini', 'Pass', 'Pass', 'No password on file')
Global $slpMed = Random(2000, 2500)
Global $slpLow = Random(100, 350)
;Not in use ATM, will be used in future builds.
Global $en = '....' ;Need to find out how to login through world #
Global $mainUrl = 'https://' & $en & '.******'
Global $testUrl = 'https://*********'

Main_GUI()

Func Main_GUI()
    AutoItSetOption("MouseCoordMode", 0)
    $EzTw = GUICreate("Ez Tw", 885, 513, -1, -1)
    GUISetBkColor(0xA0A0A0)
    $Username = GUICtrlCreateInput($nameInfo, 8, 32, 105, 21)
    GUICtrlSetBkColor(-1, 0xFFFFFF)
    $Password = GUICtrlCreateInput($passInfo, 120, 32, 105, 21)
    GUICtrlSetBkColor(-1, 0xFFFFFF)
    $LogBtn = GUICtrlCreateButton("Login", 24, 56, 75, 17)
    GUICtrlSetBkColor(-1, 0xFFFFFF)
    $UserT = GUICtrlCreateLabel("User name", 40, 8, 55, 17)
    $PassT = GUICtrlCreateLabel("Password", 144, 8, 50, 17)
    $SaveBtn = GUICtrlCreateButton("Save Info", 136, 56, 75, 17)
    GUICtrlSetBkColor(-1, 0xFFFFFF)
    $Group1 = GUICtrlCreateGroup("Group1", -16, -40, 257, 129)
    GUICtrlCreateGroup("", -99, -99, 1, 1)
    $Group2 = GUICtrlCreateGroup("Group2", 240, -16, 265, 105)
    $btnAxeLc = GUICtrlCreateButton("Axe/LC", 248, 32, 75, 17)
    $btnLcHc = GUICtrlCreateButton("Lc/Hc", 248, 8, 75, 17)
    $btnSpHc = GUICtrlCreateButton("Sp/Hc", 248, 56, 75, 17)
    $btnSwAc = GUICtrlCreateButton("Sw/Ac", 336, 8, 75, 17)
    $btnAxe = GUICtrlCreateButton("Axe Only", 336, 32, 75, 17)
    $btnSpear = GUICtrlCreateButton("Spear Only", 336, 56, 75, 17)
    $btnArcher = GUICtrlCreateButton("Archer Only", 424, 8, 75, 17)
    $btnSword = GUICtrlCreateButton("Sword Only", 424, 32, 75, 17)
    $btnMounted = GUICtrlCreateButton("MA Only", 424, 56, 75, 17)
    Global $ie = _IECreateEmbedded()
    Global $inIW = GUICtrlCreateObj($ie, 10, 100, 865, 405)
    With $ie
        .navigate("*******")
    EndWith
    GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)

    While 1
        $nMsg = GUIGetMsg()
        Switch $nMsg
            Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
                Exit
            Case $SaveBtn
                $User = GUICtrlRead($Username)
                IniWrite("Userinfo.ini", "Name", "Name", $User)
                $Pass = GUICtrlRead($Password)
                IniWrite("Userinfo.ini", "Pass", "Pass", $Pass)
            Case $LogBtn
                $User = GUICtrlRead($Username)
                $Pass = GUICtrlRead($Password)
                With $ie
                    While ($ie.busy)
                    WEnd
                    Sleep($slpLow)
                    $txtUser = .document.getElementById('user')
                    $txtUser.value = $User
                    Sleep($slpLow)
                    $txtPass = .document.getElementById('password')
                    $txtPass.value = $Pass
                    Sleep($slpLow)
                    For $a In _IETagNameGetCollection($ie, "a")
                        If StringInStr(_IEPropertyGet($a, "innerText"), "Login") Then
                            $a.fireEvent("onmousedown")
                            Sleep($slpLow)
                            $a.fireEvent("onmouseup")
                            _IEAction($a, "click")
                        EndIf
                    Next
                    Sleep($slpMed)
                EndWith
            Case $btnAxeLc
                Call('AxeLcGUI')
            Case $btnLcHc

            Case $btnSpHc

            Case $btnSwAc

            Case $btnArcher

            Case $btnAxe

            Case $btnSpear

            Case $btnSword

            Case $btnMounted

        EndSwitch
    WEnd
EndFunc

Func AxeLcGUI()
    $axeInfo = IniRead('Userinfo.ini', 'AxeLC', 'Axe', 'Not on file')
    $lcInfo = IniRead('Userinfo.ini', 'AxeLC', 'LC', 'Not on file')
    $LcForm = GUICreate("Axe / Lc", 315, 134, -1, -1)
    $AxNum = GUICtrlCreateInput($axeInfo, 32, 40, 73, 21)
    $AxNumT = GUICtrlCreateLabel("How Many Ax/run?", 24, 16, 96, 17)
    $LcNum = GUICtrlCreateInput($lcInfo, 176, 40, 73, 21)
    $LcNumT = GUICtrlCreateLabel("How many LC/run?", 168, 16, 96, 17)
    $LootAssist = GUICtrlCreateButton("Loot Assist", 32, 88, 75, 25)
    $btnSave = GUICtrlCreateButton("Save Info", 176, 88, 75, 25)
    GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)
    While 1
        $nMsg = GUIGetMsg()
        Switch $nMsg
            Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
                GUIDelete(AxeLcGUI)
                ExitLoop
            Case $btnSave
                Global $axeReal = GUICtrlRead($AxNum)
                IniWrite("Userinfo.ini", "AxeLC", "Axe", $axeReal)
                Global $lcReal = GUICtrlRead($LcNum)
                IniWrite("Userinfo.ini", "AxeLC", "LC", $lcReal)
            Case $LootAssist
                $axeReal = GUICtrlRead($AxNum)
                $lcReal = GUICtrlRead($LcNum)
                Call("AxeLCFarm")
        EndSwitch
    WEnd
EndFunc

Func AxeLCFarm()
    With $ie
        Local $oInputs = _IETagNameGetCollection($ie, "input")
        For $oInput In $oInputs
            If $oInput.name == "axe" Then
                $oInput.value = $axeReal
            EndIf
        Next
        Local $oInputs = _IETagNameGetCollection($ie, "input")
        For $oInput In $oInputs
            If $oInput.name == "light" Then
                $oInput.value = $lcReal
            EndIf
        Next
    EndWith
EndFunc

Func LootAssist()
    With $ie
        Local $oInputs = _IETagNameGetCollection($ie, "a")
        For $oInput In $oInputs
            If $oInput.title == "Loot Assistant" Then
                $oInput.fireEvent("onmousedown")
                Sleep($slpLow)
                $oInput.fireEvent("onmouseup")
                _IEAction($oInput, "click")
            EndIf
        Next
    EndWith
EndFunc

Func Farm()
    WinActivate('001')
    Send('A')
    Sleep(100)
    Send('A')
    Sleep(100)
    Send('A')
    Sleep(100)
    Send('A')
    Sleep(100)
    Send('A')
    Sleep(100)
    Send('A')
    Sleep(100)
    Send('A')
    Sleep(100)
    Send('A')
    Sleep(100)
    Send('A')
EndFunc

Func Terminate()
    Exit 0
EndFunc
```

Input to `AxeLcGUI()` also goes to the main GUI, which is undesired.

Comment: Fixed it.  Instead of using GUIs, it's much simpler and efficient to just use inputbox to gather the info, then don't have to deal with all the extra head ache.

Answer (score -1):

> … when you put any info into the pop up GUI, the main GUI reacts as well …

As per [documentation](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/GUIGetMsg.htm):

> When using the "advanced" parameter the information is returned in an array with extended information:
>   `$aArray[0]` = 0 or Event ID or Control ID
>   `$aArray[1]` = The window handle the event is from
>   `$aArray[2]` = The control handle the event is from (if applicable)
>   `$aArray[3]` = The current X position of the mouse cursor (relative to the GUI window)
>   `$aArray[4]` = The current Y position of the mouse cursor (relative to the GUI window)

`GUIGetMsg($GUI_EVENT_ARRAY)` enables identification of window from which the message originates. Example:

```
If $aArray[0] = $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE And $aArray[1] = $hGUI2 Then

    ; Your code

EndIf
```